# can not find all bluetooth devices android

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to display bluetooth devices continuously and showing them on screen but It never show me all the devices instead only 1 at a time. I can not find what I am doing wrong. here is my code, may be you can find any issue in it. Thanks

```
class monitorBluetooth extends monitor {
private ListView mLvDevices;
private ArrayList<String> mDeviceList = new ArrayList<String>();

public monitorBluetooth(service service) {

super(service);
    bluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

this.bReceiver = new  BluetoothReceiver();
}

public void finalize() throws Throwable {

super.finalize();
}

public void run() {        

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    service.registerReceiver(this.bReceiver, filter);

if(service != null) {
        bluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        bluetooth.startDiscovery();
 }       
}
class BluetoothReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetooth.getBondedDevices();

    String action = intent.getAction();

    if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
    String uuid = intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_UUID);
    int rssi = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI,Short.MIN_VALUE);
     mDeviceList.add(device.getAddress() + ", " + device.getName()); // get mac address

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mDeviceList);
            mLvDevices.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    }

}
}

BluetoothAdapter bluetooth;
private BluetoothReceiver bReceiver;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work. I wrote to LogCat what you add to `mDeviceList` and got multiple devices.

Maybe it is how you display the names or maybe there aren't more than one visible BT devices around?

**EDIT:** Added code

```
public class MonitorBluetooth extends Thread{
 BluetoothAdapter bluetooth;
 private BluetoothReceiver bReceiver;
 private Context mContext;

 public MonitorBluetooth(Context context){
  bluetooth=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
  this.bReceiver=new BluetoothReceiver();
  this.mContext=context;
 }

 public void finalize() throws Throwable{
  super.finalize();
 }

 public void run(){
  {
   IntentFilter filter=new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
   mContext.registerReceiver(this.bReceiver,filter);
  }
  {
   IntentFilter filter=new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
   mContext.registerReceiver(this.bReceiver,filter);
  }
  {
   IntentFilter filter=new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
   mContext.registerReceiver(this.bReceiver,filter);
  }
  bluetooth=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
  bluetooth.startDiscovery();
 }

 class BluetoothReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
  public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent){
   String action=intent.getAction();
   if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
    BluetoothDevice device=intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
    Log.d("BluetoothReceiver","found "+device.getAddress()+", "+device.getName());
   }
   else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)){
    Log.d("BluetoothReceiver","discovery started");
   }
   else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)){
    Log.d("BluetoothReceiver","discovery finished");
    context.unregisterReceiver(this);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

With this code, I get all the devices around by calling

```
MonitorBluetooth monitor=new MonitorBluetooth(this.getApplicationContext());
monitor.start();
```

from Activity.onCreate(Bundle)

Comment: I checked with two devices near me with bluetooth enable but I can be only one, I have tested many times

Comment: enabled!=visible, make sure they are visible also. You can add a Log.d message on top of the mDeviceList.add to see what happens. Also might make sense to register to BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED and BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.

Comment: for sure I made them visible let me try with Log.d and other intent filters you purposed

Comment: I called run directly, maybe it is a concurrency issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try something of this order:

```
public void displayDetectedDevices(){
    mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

    // Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
    mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            // When discovery finds a device
            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                String deviceName = device.getName();
                String deviceAddress = device.getAddress();
                String s = " ";
                unpairedDevices.add(deviceName + s + deviceAddress +" \n");
                unpairedDevicesList = new ArrayList<String>(unpairedDevices);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), unpairedDevicesList.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Remember in onCreate() declare the following:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    unpairedDevicesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    unpairedDevices = new HashSet<String>();
}
```

Remember #2 declare the following before onCreate():

```
ArrayList<String> unpairedDevicesList;
Set<String> unpairedDevices;
```

Final Thoughts:

I used both a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) and a [arrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) to place the detected devices in. A Set will contain no duplicates. Depending on what you want to do having both defined is helpful as they provide different functions. Also [here](https://github.com/kamilagrawala/IntellicycleV2) is my github page it contains more info and a full working bluetooth app.

As the set populates the devices will start populating the screen depending on how you want your UI to work. I used a simple list.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Bluetooth headsets. I had two bluetooth headsets and both of them were powered on, but they were not detected by the `blueToothAdapter.startDiscovery()`.

Later I found that, in case of bluetooth headsets, you need to long press the start button to activate their pairing mode to get detected by the android bluetooth discovery.

Here's a nice example of discovering nearby bluetooth devices from [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html).